# Oracle Matrix Report

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oraclereports

I have a problem with oracle matrix report.The is a lot of data in matrix so it was going on next page. I increased the width of the report . Now the problem is that the detail column of matrix is coming in one page but the header column of matrix is moving on next page.I want the header column also to be on a single page. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: let us see what you have

Answer (score 0):

"Page protect" property should be set to "Yes".

Whose? You'll have to test it - maybe repeating frame's, maybe its enclosing frame's, maybe both.